# Is a (distance-preserving map) necessarily linear?

Tags: real-analysis

Ok so I have to prove that there exists an isomorphism between 2 Banach spaces $X,Y$. My proof had five parts: 
\begin{align*}
&\text{Show $T:X\to Y$ is bijective}\\
&\text{Show $T:X\to Y$ is linear}\\
&\text{Show $T:X\to Y$ is bounded (it turned out to be an isometry)}\\
&\text{Show $T^{-1}:Y\to X$ is linear}\\
&\text{Show  $T^{-1}:Y\to X$ is bounded (it turned out to be an isometry)}\\
\end{align*}

What's the shortest way to do the proof? It seems here that some steps were redundant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If a linear map is bijective, the inverse is always linear, so that step is redundant. For a linear map between Banach spaces, the open mapping theorem gives the continuity of the inverse provided $T$ is continuous and bijective (but for an isometry, appealing to the open mapping theorem is no gain over directly stating the continuity of the isometric inverse).

Comment: To answer the question in the title: a distance preserving map needn't be linear. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be linear and distance preserving. Then $f+\tilde{x}$ is distance preserving but non-linear. Perhaps a weaker statement is true, that every distance preserving map is [affine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your insight!